# Moving man pages with ruby and homebrew

Tags: ruby, shell, homebrew, manpage

To my understanding there is `prefix.install 'name'` and `bin.install` that install a file at the location of `/usr/local/Cellar/` and the other the bin.

However I want to move a manual page of my script to `/usr/local/share/man/man1`, how would i go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error `man[number].install 'name.[number]'` installs the file at its appropiate location